# Why is my code reading orphaned case?

Tags: java, switch-statement

Writing some code for a text based D&D campaign and I'm trying to get the method `Weapon()` to recall what character was chosen at the beginning and let the user choose their weapon. I've written a switch statement inside a switch statement to allow the case of chosen character to ask for the case of desired weapon. The plan is to use this before each combat sequence.

Why is it telling me `EBERK` is an orphaned case?

```
public static String Weapon() {
    String weapon = "Unarmed";

    switch (chooseCharacter()) {
        case TORDEK:
            System.out.println("Choose Weapon: ");
            System.out.println("1. War Axe \n2. Bow \n3. Unarmed");
            System.out.print("Weapon Selection (1-3): ");
            int menuChoice = KBD.nextInt();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("Press Enter...");
            System.out.println();
            KBD.nextLine();
            System.out.println();

            while (menuChoice > 3 || menuChoice < 1) {
                System.out.print("Please enter 1 through 3: ");
                menuChoice = KBD.nextInt();
                System.out.println();
                KBD.nextLine();
            }
            switch (menuChoice) {
                case 1:
                    weapon = "War Axe";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    weapon = "Bow";
                    break;
                default:
                    weapon = "Unarmed";
                    break;
            }
            return weapon;
            break;

        case EBERK:
            System.out.println("Choose Weapon: ");
            System.out.println("1. Warhammer \n2. Crossbow \n3. Unarmed");
            System.out.print("Weapon Selection (1-3): ");
            int menuChoice = KBD.nextInt();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("Press Enter...");
            System.out.println();
            KBD.nextLine();
            System.out.println();

            while (menuChoice > 3 || menuChoice < 1) {
                System.out.print("Please enter 1 through 3: ");
                menuChoice = KBD.nextInt();
                System.out.println();
                KBD.nextLine();

                switch (menuChoice) {
                    case 1:
                        weapon = "Warhammer";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        weapon = "Crossbow";
                        break;
                    default:
                        weapon = "Unarmed";
                        break;
                }
                break;
       // case JOZAN:   etc....
```

Comment: `return weapon;` probably... It's pointless to break after a return

Comment: You should always post the exact and complete error message when asking about an error.

Comment: You're missing a closing `}` after the second `while`

Comment: Removed the return weapon; statement and added a closing } after the second while and they removed some of the errors, thanks!

Comment: Now case 2 where weapon = "Crossbow"; is saying orphaned case for all remaining heroes.

Comment: Nevermind, solved it. Was missing more braces. Thanks everyone!